# How to use QTimer singleShot with QEventLoop in Qt

Tags: qt, qdialog, qtimer, qeventloop

I need to open QDialog by using QTimer singleShot and wait for a status flag. If this variable is true then continue.

This is my code

> StatusFlag = FALSE;

```
void MainWindow::OpenWindow()
{
   qDebug("OpenWindow"); 
   NewGUI *gui=new NewGUI();
   gui->setModal(true);
   gui->exec();
}
void MainWindow::mWait(ulong milliSeconds)
{
    QEventLoop loop;
    QTimer::singleShot(milliSeconds, &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();
}
```

> In NewGUI constructor StatusFlag is set to TRUE

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(OpenWindow()));
while(StatusFlag == FALSE)
{
   //Wait until StatusFlag is TRUE.
   qDebug("Enter"); 
   mWait(1);
   qDebug("Exit");         
}

if(StatusFlag == TRUE)
{
   //Do something
   qDebug("Do something");  
}
```

Current Output is

```
Enter 
OpenWindow
```

Expected Output is

```
Enter 
Exit
OpenWindow
Do something
```

If i comment the line

> QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(OpenWindow()));

Then the output is

```
Enter 
Exit.. still continuing
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Don't use any kind of waiting mechanism in your GUI thread. It's event driven programming. Take advantage of that. Use signals and slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `gui->exec();` starts a new local event loop so you never come out of `OpenWindow()`. So your while loop will block in `mWait(1);` until you close the dialog.

Instead of setting a flag, you can emit a signal in the NewGUI constructor to which you can connect a slot of MainWindow. You can do whatever the work you need to do in this slot.